# Creative solution for a crippled zpool (aka help a dying raid to survive for 1-2 weeks)

Tags: zfs, mdadm, zpool, raidz

I have a ZFS RAIDZ-7 made by 8x4TB on a Proxmox 6 (linux kernel version: 5.4.78-2-pve, openZFS version: 0.8.5-pve1).

An unfortunate astral conjunction force me to remove 3 disk from my RAIDZ.
In around 1 or 2 weeks 5 new disks comes to me.

Not too bad, raidz7 can suffer 3 loss. BUT one on the remaining disk is dying (slowly, I suppose can survive for some time).

I have a 2TB and a 3TB disk available right now.

So I thought about building an mdadm strip array with the 2TB and 3TB and use the resultant 5TB raid as a disk for the raidz.

There is a pure zfs alternative? Is possible to create a VDEV with the 2TB+3TB disk and use it as a disk for the RAID-Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ZFS currently does not support concatenated devices to be used as a mirror leg. You must first use `md` or `lvm` to concatenate the two devices, the issue `zpool replace` to replace one of the removed disk.

Such a setup is only good for short-term data recovery; I would not use it for longer than strictly required.

Comment: I'll plan to use it no more than the RMA time.
Thank you for the reply.